# Why is justify-content not working vertically?

Tags: html, css, responsive

The buttons are displayed vertically in a rectangle menu. When they are justified with justify-content: space-around everything works as expected but whe using justify-content: space-between; they are just flood in the first part of the rectangle. Why is this happening?

Because this is an Angular component the rectangle is actually main:

```
main{
border: 2px solid white;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
height:80vh;
}

<main class="flex-container space-between">
<ul >
<li class="flex-item container">a</li>
<li class="flex-item container">a</li>
<li class="flex-item container">a</li>
<li class="flex-item container">a</li>
<li class="flex-item container">a</li>
<li class="flex-item container">a</li>
</ul>
</main>
```

Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, so removed the tag.

Comment: use css on `ul` tag instead of `main` tag

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're applying all the styles to main, where you should be applying the flex CSS to the ul.

Answer (score 0):

Because  `justify-content:space-between;` has items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the start line, last item on the end line.

This makes your first item [ul] in the start line [first row because you have `flex-direction : column;`] .